# How to debug curl when netcat works?

Tags: networking, tcp, curl, netcat

The following cURL command hangs:

```
$ curl -v http://1.1.1.1/*
   Trying 1.1.1.1:80...
* Connected to 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) port 80
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 1.1.1.1
> User-Agent: curl/8.3.0
> Accept: */*
> 
^C
```

Yet, if I copy that request into a file and send it with Netcat, it works??

```
$ cat req
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 1.1.1.1
User-Agent: curl/8.3.0
Accept: */*


$ cat req | nc -N -v 1.1.1.1 80
Connection to 1.1.1.1 80 port [tcp/http] succeeded!
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: cloudflare
Date: Tue, 10 Oct 2023 18:44:58 GMT
... snipped rest of response ...
```

**Question**: What techniques can I use to debug this problem further? I already put verbose flags on cURL and Netcat.

---

The only interesting thing strace shows me is that cURL calls something called `/var/run/nscd/socket` whereas netcat does not. But I don't see how that would affect the TCP connection to a direct IP address. (thanks for Steffan Ullrich for telling me I needed to track %net and %file)

Comment: *"Where the heck did my HTTP request go in netcat?"* - it is using `write` not `sendto`. But write is not a network related system call but a more generic call. It is not covered by  `strace -e %net`.